# Linked lists, students to a subject

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to register students and subjects, then add a student to a subject. All this using linked lists in Java.

So far I can add students and subjects and show the list of them but I’m not able to “link” them and show what students are taking what subject.

Code here:

```
package examenfinal;

/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public class Alumno {
    private int ID;
    private String Nombre;
    private int Carne;

    public Alumno(int Id, String nombre, int carne) {
        this.ID = Id;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Carne = carne;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int Id) {
        this.ID = Id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getCarne() {
        return Carne;
    }

    public void setCarne(int carne) {
        this.Carne = carne;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno{" + "ID=" + ID + ", Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Carne=" + Carne + '}';
    }


}
```

```java
package examenfinal;
import java.util.LinkedList;
/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public class Curso {
    private int Codigo;
    private String Nombre;
    private int Ciclo;
    private int Año;
    private LinkedList<Alumno> Asignar;

    public Curso() {
    }


    public Curso(int codigo, String nombre, int ciclo, int año) {
        this.Codigo = codigo;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Ciclo = ciclo;
        this.Año = año;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return Codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int Codigo) {
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public int getCiclo() {
        return Ciclo;
    }

    public void setCiclo(int Ciclo) {
        this.Ciclo = Ciclo;
    }

    public int getAño() {
        return Año;
    }

    public void setAño(int Año) {
        this.Año = Año;
    }

    public void RegristrarAlumno(int carne, String nombre, int id){
        Asignar.add(new Alumno(carne, nombre, id));
    }

    public LinkedList<Alumno> getAsignar() {
        return Asignar;
    }    
}
```

```java
package examenfinal;
import java.util.LinkedList;
/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public class Universidad {
    private LinkedList<Alumno> Inscritos;
    private LinkedList<Curso> Cursos;


    public Universidad()
    {
        Inscritos = new LinkedList<>();
        Cursos = new LinkedList<>();
    }            


    public void Crear_Curso(int cod_curso, String nombre, int ciclo, int año){
        this.Cursos.add(new Curso(cod_curso, nombre, ciclo, año));
    }
    public void Crear_Alumno(int id, String nombre, int carne){
        this.Inscritos.add(new Alumno(id, nombre, carne));
    }
    public void Asignar_Alumno_a_Curso(Curso curso, Alumno alumno){
        curso.RegristrarAlumno(0, alumno.getNombre(), 0);
    }
    public LinkedList<Curso> getCursos(){
        return Cursos;
    }
    public LinkedList<Alumno> getInscritos(){
        return Inscritos;
    }
}
```

```java
package examenfinal;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public final class InterfaceConsola {
    private Alumno alumno1;
    private Curso curso1;
    private Universidad universidad1;
    private Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);        
    private int Opcion;

    public void CrearCurso(){
        System.out.println("INFORMACION DEL CURSO");

        int Id;
        String Nombre; 
        int Ciclo;
        int Año;

        System.out.println("CODIGO: ");
        Id=(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("NOMBRE: ");
        Nombre = (in.next());
        System.out.println("CICLO: ");
        Ciclo = (in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("AÑO: ");
        Año = (in.nextInt());

        universidad1.Crear_Curso(Id, Nombre, Ciclo, Año);

    }

    public void CrearAlumno(){
        System.out.println("\nINGRESE LA INFORMACION DEL ALUMNO");
        System.out.println("\nID: ");
        int Id;
        String Nombre;
        int Carne;

        Id = (in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("\nNOMBRE: ");
        Nombre = (in.next());
        System.out.println("\nNO. CARNE: ");
        Carne = (in.nextInt());
        universidad1.Crear_Alumno(Id, Nombre, Carne);



    }
    public void MostrarCursos()
    {
        System.out.println("CURSOS REGISTRADOS: ");
        LinkedList<Curso> Cursos = universidad1.getCursos();



        Iterator it =Cursos.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())                   
        {
            Curso cursoActual = (Curso) it.next();
            System.out.println(cursoActual.getNombre());
        }

    }

    public void MostrarAlumnos()
    {
        System.out.println("ALUMNOS REGISTRADOS: ");
        LinkedList<Alumno> Alumnos = universidad1.getInscritos();

        Iterator it =Alumnos.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())                   
        {
            Alumno AlumnoActual = (Alumno) it.next();
            System.out.println(AlumnoActual.getNombre());
        }

    }

    public void AsignarAlumnos(){
    }

    public int Menu()
    {

       System.out.println("UNIVERSIDAD MARIANO GALVEZ DE GUATEMALA");
       System.out.println("\tMENU");
       System.out.println("\n1.   INGRESAR ALUMNO");
       System.out.println("2.   MOSTRAR ALUMNOS INSCRITOS");
       System.out.println("3.   CREAR CURSO");
       System.out.println("4.   MOSTRAR CURSOS");
       System.out.println("5.   ASIGNAR ALUMNOS POR CURSO");
       System.out.println("6.   MOSTRAR ALUMNOS POR CURSO");
       System.out.println("7.   SALIR");
       System.out.println("SELECCIONE UNA OPCION: ");
       return in.nextInt();

    }

   public InterfaceConsola(){       
       universidad1= new Universidad();
   }

   public void Operacion()
   {
     int opcion = Menu();
       while (opcion!= 7)
       {
           if (opcion == 1)
               CrearAlumno();

           if (opcion == 2)
               MostrarAlumnos();

           if (opcion == 3)
               CrearCurso();

           if (opcion == 4)
               MostrarCursos(); 

           if (opcion == 5)
               AsignarAlumnos(); 

           opcion = Menu();
       }
   }
}
```

```java
package examenfinal;

/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public class ExamenFinal {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        InterfaceConsola inter1 = new InterfaceConsola();
        inter1.Operacion();
    }

}
```

Comment: so what happens?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the student from the student list and add a subject from the subject list to another list I guess to then see wich subjects is the student taking, I get null

Comment: Sorry but there is not Student in your code and no Subject as well. You shall rephrase the question according to your code I believe.

Comment: Student=Estudiante, Subject= Curso, the "new list" is Universidad=college wich will contain the students per subject

Comment: I would advise you only post code relevant to the issue. It makes it far more challenging to look through all of your code to target the issue.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to refactor `Curso` to accept an existing `Alumno`

```
public void RegristrarAlumno(Alumno alumno){
   Asignar.add(alumno);
}
```

next in your `InterfaceConsola#AsignarAlumnos` you must do ask for student id,
retrieve the student from LinkedList.

```
public void AsignarAlumnos(){
   System.out.println("\nINGRESE LA ID DEL ALUMNO");
   int alumnoId = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("\nINGRESE LA ID DEL CURSO");
   int cursoId = in.nextInt();
   List<Alumno> insrictos = universidad1.getInscritos();
   Alumno alumno = null;
   for(Iterator<Alumno> iteratorDelInstrictos = instritos.iterator(); iteratorDelInsritos.hasNext();){
      Alumno testAlumno = iteratorDelInsritos.next();
      if(testAlumno.getId() == alumnoId ){
          alumno = testAlumno;
          break;
      }
   }

   if(alumno == null){
      System.out.println("Alumno not found);
      return;
   }

   Curso curso = null;
   for(Iterator<Curso> iteratorDelCursos = universidad.getCursos().iterator(); iteratorDelCursos.hasNext();){
      Curso testCurso = iteratorDelCursos.next();
      if(testCurso.getCodigo() == cursoId){
          curso = testCurso;
          break;
      }
   }
   if(curso == null){
      System.out.println("Curso not found);
      return;
   }
   curso.RegristrarAlumno(alumno);
```

Also you need to follow Java naming guidelines (all variables are lowercase), and use generics for your iterators.

Comment: this will send it to the "LinkedList<Alumno> Asignar;" right?

Comment: ok I think i fixed it but i have a problem showing the assinged students should I edit the quiestion or ask a new one?

Comment: depends on whether or not it's the same issue or a brand new one

Answer (score 0):

With a little less of understanding of the question and considering -

> `Alumno` must be Student, and `Curso` is presumably Subject

Every `Curso` seem to have a list of `Alumno` attached to it.

```
private LinkedList<Alumno> Asignar
```

To modify/create this list, you need to

```
private Universidad universidad1 = new Universidad();
universidad1.getCursos().get(i).getAsignar().add(new Alumno());
```

where `i` would be the index of the `Curso` you're willing to update and you can replace `new Alumno()` with an instance of `Alumno` that you want to add to the list within `Curso`.